# How to run an android app with google maps from github

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2, api-key

Before I go any further, I would like everyone to know that I don't have much experience with android, so any little help will be great.

I saw this amazing project at a hackathon and they redirected me to their github (https://github.com/TuanNASavvycom/Wonolo-Coding-Challenge) to test it out.

This project uses Google Maps API so I know I need an API key, and I have got an API key by

```
creating a new project on Android Studios--->
Selecting Map template ----> 
Going to link on the project's Google Maps API XML file ----->
Generating the API ----->
```

Replaced the Developers API (which did not work) with mine, and I get this error:

`Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.`

And it told me to visit some android Google maps api link which didn't give much information

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Could anyone give me any guidance as to what to do if I want to run this app?

Answer (score 0):

You should able to do it once you change the key under `android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"` in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

For the key set up, go to developer console, and create an `Android Key` when you clicked `create new key`. Look at the error message for the fingerprint for your application:

```
07-21 11:20:26.493  11416-11996/? E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: AIzaSyB1wy3NjUeJrkiLxa-isYlZPF3PI_UGORo
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): D0:DE:22:BB:6E:7C:F6:D0:55:9A:CE:40:47:18:F7:EC:1C:CD:68:51;com.savvycom.wonolocodingchallenge
```

which should look something like:
`D0:DE:22:BB:6E:7C:F6:D0:55:9A:CE:40:47:18:F7:EC:1C:CD:68:51;com.savvycom.wonolocodingchallenge`

and paste it in the `Accept requests from an Android application with one of the certificate fingerprints and package names listed below (Optional)` box, and click Create.

Yes, the key is "Optional", and you can leave it empty, which would allow all application in the world to use your key to gain access to Google Maps as you. You can do it for the private testing purpose.